# Utilizing webhooks to gain knowledge of a successful payment to load customers account on website

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to write a piece of code that will receive a webhook to notify me of a successful transaction. Once the webhook sends data back to my website I would then like to utilize the information to load the customers account on my website with the correct information.

For example;

A customer buys 100 coins > Payment is successful > The webhook fires and sends this information back containing how many coins were purchased > The information is then converted to load the account on the website

I am struggling with creating the receiving end on my website. Has anyone successfully built something similar?

I have set up the webhooks and they fire, I just can't seem to get the correct information to pull and convert that to the website wallet.

Code Tried below;

```
<?php
// Load WordPress functions
require_once('wp-load.php');

// Load Stripe PHP library
require_once('path/to/stripe-php/init.php');

// Set your Stripe API key
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_12345');

// Define the user meta key for the virtual wallet
$virtual_wallet_key = 'virtual_wallet';

// Define the number of coins to add for each successful payment
$coins_per_payment = 100;

// Listen for the Stripe webhook
$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event = null;
try {
    $event = \Stripe\Event::constructFrom(
        json_decode($payload, true)
    );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    // Invalid payload
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
}

// Handle the payment succeeded event
if ($event->type === 'payment_intent.succeeded') {
    $paymentIntent = $event->data->object;
    $customer_id = $paymentIntent->customer;
    $coins = (int) get_user_meta($customer_id, $virtual_wallet_key, true);
    $coins += $coins_per_payment;
    update_user_meta($customer_id, $virtual_wallet_key, $coins);
}

http_response_code(200);
?>
```

I cannot seem to get the right meta data or find the right metadata for the wallets to link up.

Comment: Show the code that you have already tried.